# Start Menu - Hover Folder Show Contents

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

After I pin a folder to the start menu, can I do something so that I hover over the folder and am able to view the contents?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you can add a folder as a toolbar to the Taskbar instead. You might also find [7stacks](http://alastria.com/software/7stacks/) or [StandaloneStack](http://www.chrisnsoft.com/standalonestack) useful.

Comment: 7stacks was pretty nifty. Thanks!